# Regex in Java for a Squence(5 letter,1number,2 letter)

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for checking if the input string is in this sequence 
(5 letter,1number,2 letter) ex:ABCDE1FG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your regex

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$"
```

Comment: @ppeterka it's a regex, what did you expect?

Comment: what if i don't have these start "^" and "$" ,still it seems to work

Comment: @DDN if you don't have those, than you will match any string that contains your sequence, even if it has extra stuff too like `AACDABCDE1FGq1_a`  `^` means beginning of input, and `$` means the end of input.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regular expression:

```
[A-Z]{5}[0-9][A-Z]{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the briefest way to express it:

```
[A-Z]{5}\d[A-Z]{2}
```

If by "letters" you want lowercase letters to be allowed too, add the "case insensitive" switch:

```
(?i)[A-Z]{5}\d[A-Z]{2}
```

Note that for java, you must double the backslashes when coding a String, so `"[A-Z]{5}\\d[A-Z]{2}"` etc

Answer (score -1):

One possible example: `\\w{5}\\d\\w{2}`

Comment: `\w` can also match numbers and underscores:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html